# jquery check if username already in database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Every time when someone types something in the inputfield, I use ajax to check if the username already exists. But this query is very slow. I uploaded the page and it need 2-5s for this query. I use this code here

```
$('#register_username').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_username.php",
        data: "username="+value
        success: function(response){
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

In `check_username.php` is only a sql statement. 
Im using a free webspace at the moment (lima-city.de). Is that the problem maybe?

You can test it [here](http://skeptar1.lima-city.de/register), enter in the first inputfield **Benutzername**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if username exists in database with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762478/check-if-username-exists-in-database-with-ajax)

Comment: We do not know your query and your db structure. So we cannot tell you why it is slow. Maybe an index for your database field should help. But who knows without knowing your db structure.

Comment: *"But this query is very slow."* - so, what does your question have to do with jQuery? How do we know your DB isn't properly indexed? we also don't know how your code is setup for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do on `focusout` like below, and check once:-

```
$(document).bind('focusout','#register_username', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_username.php",
        data: "username="+value
        success: function(response){
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:- Not only this it will depend on your query code also, that how much efficient it is. that means it will be optimized to give result in minimum amount of time. May be some problem is there also.I am  not sure about that**

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the blur event. It will send the query only once you loose focus of the input field.