# Issues checking if username exists using ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, validation, escaping, sanitization

I have a problem and a question for the code below.

1. The code below performs a live check if username already exists in database. Now when I enter username manually it all works fine with giving live success or error message as the case is but when after typing 1 or 2 characters I choose username from autofill options given by browser It doesn't give any success or error message instead keeps showing **Enter 3 to 11 characters** which is initial message for username requirements. Can't figure out why it doesn't work when username is selected from autofill options.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#un').keyup(function(){
    var username = $(this).val();
    var Result = $('#result'); 
    if(username.length > 2 || username.length > 11) { // if greater than 2 (minimum 3)
        Result.html('./img/loadgreen.gif');
        var dataPass = 'action=availability&username='+username;
        $.ajax({ // Send the username val to available.php
        type : 'POST',
        data : dataPass,
        url  : 'available.php',
        success: function(responseText){ // Get the result
            if(responseText == 0){
                Result.html('<span class="success">Available</span>');
            }
            else if(responseText > 0){
                Result.html('<span class="error">Unavailable</span>');
            }
            else{
                alert('Problem with sql query');
            }
        }
        });
    }else{
        Result.html('Enter 3 to 11 characters');
    }
    if(username.length == 0) {
        Result.html('');
    }
 });
});
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" id="un"  placeholder="Username" class="username" />
</td>
<td class="result" id="result"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

available.php

```
<?php
include ( "./inc/connect.php" );
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'availability')
{
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $que=$db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
   $que->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
   $count = $que->rowCount();
   echo $count;
}
?>
```

2. Now my question is how to secure `POST` on `available.php` lot of people tell you need to sanitize or escape every `POST` and `GET` data. So what works best with PDO. Also heard escaping doesn't works with PDO may be I am wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762478/check-if-username-exists-in-database-with-ajax?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try jquery [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of .keyup()