# Check if value exist in Mysql Database on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm updating an item (**ativo**) of an employee (**colaborador**) I need to check if an employee that the user input exists or not in the DB, and if it doesn't - give an error message. I don't know how can I do it, can you guys point me to some tutorial that explains it? Thanks in advance!
This is my query btw:

```
 $pdo = Database::connect();

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "UPDATE ativos SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?,
                localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?, 
                imei = ?, numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?, 
                anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ?,
                id_colaborador = (SELECT id_colaborador 
                                    FROM colaboradores 
                                    WHERE nome = ? 
                                    LIMIT 1
                                  ) 
        WHERE id_ativo = ?";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,
            $fabricante,$modelo,$imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,
            $anexo_a,$evento,$data_evento,$id_colaborador,$id));
```

And this is the input (i don't know if it's needed to validate if the row exist)

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="id_colaborador" type="text"  placeholder="Nome do Colaborador" value="<?php echo !empty($nome)?$nome:'';?>" class='auto'>
```

Comment: I guess what you need is AJAX, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762478/check-if-username-exists-in-database-with-ajax

Comment: One mistake is is referencing the id_colaborador with #nome# and not with ID.
First for all, I'll reference colaborador by  ID and pass it to the UPDATE to just do UPDATE bla bla WHERE id = $idColaborador

Comment: @Roy but the app is getting the `$id_colaborador` when the user inputs the `$nome` that's now the problem I'm getting haha

Comment: Simple answer is, first do a select of the colaborator if you get a row back you will have the benefit of being able to use the rows `id` in the update query and if you dont get a row back you throw an error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly but if the value is blank I can validade if and show it as an error like this [link](http://prntscr.com/lwf4v9)

Comment: Well then you either have to repaint the page, OR, you have to learn some AJAX so you can do it all without having to round trip the whole page

Comment: @CarlosSantiago but you're searching id by nome... and that maybe a problem if colaborador has the same name.

Comment: @Roy but for that I have a div that display the ID so the user can choose the correct employee even if the name is the same

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not considering the possibility of homonyms. So, you'd better use some auto_complete field to get the 'id_colaborador' based on the name and keep it in a hidden input field and then execute the update with the exact values.

Comment: I have the autocomplete, but it won't prevent the user to input a employee that doesn't exist..