# How can I verify the input of a form before insert in a database with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, onsubmit

I have a signup form, and I would like to verify it before entering the data in the database.
Verify if the phone number is all numeric, then compare the username in the database to see if it is already existing, and if it's all good, register in the database.

At first, I was using this :

```js
<?php 

session_start();
include("connection.php");
include("fonctions.php");

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        //Récupérer les data de la variable post
        $prenom = $_POST['txtPrenom'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$prenom);
        $nom = $_POST['txtNom'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$nom);
        $adresseMail = $_POST['txtAdresseMail'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$adresseMail);
        $numeroGSM = $_POST['txtGSM'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$numeroGSM);
        $identifiant = $_POST['txtIdentifiant'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$identifiant);
        $motDePasse = $_POST['txtMotDePasse'];
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$motDePasse);
        $refClient = random_num(20);
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$refClient);
        $invite = 0;
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$invite);


        if (!empty($prenom) && !empty($nom) && !empty($adresseMail) && !empty($numeroGSM) && !empty($identifiant) && !empty($motDePasse))
        {
            if (!is_numeric($numeroGSM))
            {

                //alert("Numéro de GSM invalide");

            }
            else 
            {
                $identifiantPresent = "SELECT identifiant FROM tblclient where identifiant = '".$identifiant."' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $identifiantPresent);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    alert("Identifiant existe déjà");

                }
                else
                {
                    //Enregistrement dans la base de données
                    $query = "insert into tblclient(refClient,prenom,nom,adresseMail,numeroGSM,identifiant,motDePasse,invite) values ('$refClient','$prenom','$nom','$adresseMail','$numeroGSM','$identifiant','$motDePasse','$invite')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    alertHeader("Compte crée avec succès","../index.php");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>La Cour des Dames</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="/CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="Contenaire">
                <header id="FondBanniere">
                    <img src="../Images/Logo.jpeg" id="Banniere">
                </header>

        <link href="../CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="persoNav">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button id="btnAccueil" class="nav-link">Accueil</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<form method="post">
    <table class="tableauInscription">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Formulaire d'inscription</h3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="coteGauche">Prenom :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtPrenom" id="txtPrenom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Prenom"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Nom :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtNom" id="txtNom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nom"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Adresse email :</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="txtAdresseMail" id="txtAdresseMail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email"></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">GSM min 7 :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtGSM" id="txtGSM" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="GSM" minlength="7"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Identifiant :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtIdentifiant" id="txtIdentifiant" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Mot de passe : </td>
            <td><input type="Password" name="txtMotDePasse" id="txtMotDePasse" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche"></td>
            <td style="padding-left:33px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
                <button type="submit" id="btnCreerCompte" class="btn btn-dark">Créer le compte</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
    </body>

    <!-- PARTIE SCRIPT -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btnAccueil").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "../index.php";
    };
    </script>

</html>
```

But the problem was the page was refreshing after an alert was display, so I search for that and i found the " onsubmit", but now the problem is that I need to do all of this in my function :

```js
<?php 

session_start();
include("connection.php");
include("fonctions.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>La Cour des Dames</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="/CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function valide_GSM() {
        var prenom = document.getElementById("txtPrenom").value;
        var nom = document.getElementById("txtNom").value;
        var mail = document.getElementById("txtAdresseMail").value;
        var numGSM = document.getElementById("txtGSM").value;
        var identifiant = document.getElementById("txtIdentifiant").value;
        var motDePasse = document.getElementById("txtMotDePasse").value;


        if (!empty(prenom) && !empty(nom) && !empty(adresseMail) && !empty(numeroGSM) && !empty(identifiant) && !empty(motDePasse))
        {
            if (isNaN(numGSM))
            {
                alert("Numéro de gsm non valide");
                //Phone number invalid
                document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                identifiantPresent = "SELECT identifiant FROM tblclient where identifiant = '".identifiant."' ";
                result = mysqli_query(con, identifiantPresent);

                if (mysqli_num_rows(result) > 0)
                {
                    alert("Identifiant existe déjà");
                    //Username already existing

                }
                else
                {
                    //Enregistrement dans la base de données
                    //Registration in the database
                    query = "insert into tblclient(refClient,prenom,nom,adresseMail,numeroGSM,identifiant,motDePasse,invite) values ('refClient','prenom','nom','adresseMail','numeroGSM','identifiant','motDePasse','invite')";
                    mysqli_query(con, query);
                    alertHeader("Compte crée avec succès","../index.php");
                    //Account created successfully
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
            //Please fill all input box
        }
        return true;
    }
  </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="Contenaire">
                <header id="FondBanniere">
                    <img src="../Images/Logo.jpeg" id="Banniere">
                </header>

        <link href="../CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="persoNav">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button id="btnAccueil" class="nav-link">Accueil</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return valide_GSM();">
    <table class="tableauInscription">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Formulaire d'inscription</h3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="coteGauche">Prenom :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtPrenom" id="txtPrenom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Prenom"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Nom :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtNom" id="txtNom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nom"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Adresse email :</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="txtAdresseMail" id="txtAdresseMail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email"></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">GSM min 7 :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtGSM" id="txtGSM" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="GSM" minlength="7"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Identifiant :</td>
            <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtIdentifiant" id="txtIdentifiant" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche">Mot de passe : </td>
            <td><input type="Password" name="txtMotDePasse" id="txtMotDePasse" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  class="coteGauche"></td>
            <td style="padding-left:33px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
                <button type="submit" id="btnCreerCompte" class="btn btn-dark">Créer le compte</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
    </body>

    <!-- PARTIE SCRIPT -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btnAccueil").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "../index.php";
    };
    </script>

</html>
```

And obviously this doesn't work, but I'm a little stuck, I don't know how to adapt or where to look for my research. Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Edit your question to include your HTML form. Without, we will have a hard time debugging your issue.

Comment: @disinfor Hi, here is, I edited and put the full code

Comment: You can use `ajax` to validate. Does this answer your question? [Check if username exists in database with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762478/check-if-username-exists-in-database-with-ajax)

Comment: @NcXNaV I don't know about ajax, do you think this can solve my issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Ajax code. You'll need another `php` check-user.php to check if user existed.

Note:

1. Try using Ajax, start from simple. It can improve overall user experience. AJAX allows you to do checks with the server without refreshing the page. Try this simple [example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-ajax-form-validation-example-from-scratchexample.html). But note that users can disable javascript, so it's always a good idea to validate forms both in client and server side, just maintain your `php` validation.
2. Beware that your code is wide open to [SQL Injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should use parameterized prepared statements instead. Check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) out.

**Form Validation** with **JQuery** and **Ajax** in mainForm.php

```
$('#btnCreerCompte').on('click',function(e){
   //prevent submitting form
   e.preventDefault();
  
   //Get Input Values
   var prenom = document.getElementById("txtPrenom").value;
   var nom = document.getElementById("txtNom").value;
   var mail = document.getElementById("txtAdresseMail").value;
   var numGSM = document.getElementById("txtGSM").value;
   var identifiant = document.getElementById("txtIdentifiant").value;
   var motDePasse = document.getElementById("txtMotDePasse").value;
   
   //Form Validation
   if (prenom && nom && mail && numGSM && identifiant && motDePasse){
       if (isNaN(numGSM)){
           alert("Numéro de gsm non valide");
           //Phone number invalid
           document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();
           return false;
       }
       else{
           //Call Ajax to check if user existed
           $.ajax({ 
             type    : "POST",
             url     : "check-user.php",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
              //data you need for php query, to check if user existed
              //Use $_POST['identifiant'] in check-user.php
              identifiant: identifiant
             },           
             success:function(result) {
               // alert(result.msg);
               if (result.msg == "Success"){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 //Submit form if user not existed
                 $('form').submit(); 
               }
               else if (result.msg == "Failed"){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 alert("User Existed!");
               }
             }
           });
       }
   }
   else{
      alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
      return false;
   }
   
});
```

**PHP**: check-user.php

```
<?php
   //DB Connection
   $con = ..;  

   $identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];

   $identifiantPresent = "SELECT identifiant FROM tblclient where identifiant = '".$identifiant."' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $identifiantPresent);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      $arr = array('msg' => "Failed");
   }
   else{
      $arr = array('msg' => "Success");
   }

   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the wrong variable names. For example, in your JS (IF statement), the variable is `mail` instead of `adresseMail`. Correct those variables and then try once.

Also, in your function, whenever you are displaying alert for invalid fields or any fields, just add `return false`. This will ensure that the processing stops and the function does not return `true` by default when there's an error.

Here's the changes:

```
var mail = document.getElementById("txtAdresseMail").value; // rename to adresseMail
var numGSM = document.getElementById("txtGSM").value; // rename to numeroGSM
...
...
else
    {
        alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
        //Please fill all input box
        return false; // ADD THIS
    }
```

Keep your JavaScript separate from your PHP code to make it more readable.

Comment: I did all the thing you told me to do, but i guess it's not working, beacause when i click on sign up button, all box cleared themself

Comment: It's probably because your form was submitted and page got reloaded (which is the expected behavior of submit buttons). Can you share a working example of your code?

Comment: Look in my original post, i've edited it, so the whole code is here

Comment: I don't see return false in your last alert statement. What's the behavior with your latest code? I don't have a PHP server so I cannot test it locally.

Comment: Oh I forget to add it but there was a return false after all alert except the one where all is fine. 
Here I use the code NcXNaV gave me, and for that problem, it works. Thank you for your time  and your help !

Comment: Not a problem! :)